# Windows 7 Intermittent Connection Issues (Repeatedly "identifying")

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I have an issue solely with my desktop windows 7 machine on my network (the network has multiple different devices, on the same and different operating systems) and the issue is that irregularly, although sometimes frequently, I briefly get disconnected from the internet (briefly is for around 5-10 seconds).

However, I never loose the bars on the wifi thing, eg I don't get the yellow triangle, but it goes to the identifying stage and then reconnects.

The reason I noticed the problem was when I was streaming music it would stop and I would refresh the page and it would start working again ( turned out it was because it took that amount of time to get connected again).

So my question is, what would cause the intermittent issues and start the "identifying" process again. I don't think its my router, because no one else is having problems, so the other option is that its a problem specifically with my machine.

I'm connecting to a Netgear DG834GT router, and I'm using a Edimax Wireless-N150 USB Adapter.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what it was. Something to do with a virtual machine that,for some reason, had done something to the actual wireless device when it was setting up the virtual one for the virtual machine.

Very odd and has never happened before :P magic eh :P

Thanks all :D

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my laptop. Try going into the Power Settings and changing the wireless power saving mode to 'Maximum Performance'

[image]

For me the problem was with the Centrino chipset. It implements this feature called Power Save Poll which is horribly broken and breaks wifi connectivity on many routers.

Comment: hey thanks for the response, but I'm having an issue with desktop pc. I should have mentioned that in the initial post and having just checked the power settings its already set to maximum performance.

Thanks very much for the input, good to rule things out :D